# Excel - VB, Copying contents from one row and appending that row at the bottom of previouslty appended rows

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching and searching and although I've come across some very helpful code, I'm struggling to adjust the code to make fit for my exact application.

What I'm trying to achieve:

[REFERENCE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tscYN.png)

I need to copy the contents of Row (21) and append them AFTER itself - Row (previous + 1) whilst maintaining consecutive formulas, so that WP# increases by 1. I need this newly generated row to fit before the currently Row 24 (but obviously Row 24 will increase it's row count as the user clicks "Add Waypoint"), as I'll be using this row to sum totals of the formulas calculated in the preceding rows above it.

I hope this makes sense, as I just confused myself whilst writing it!!

In context, the user is looking to insert WP NAME, Longitude & Latitude, Lane - Course, Distance, DTG and Voyage time will all be calculations utilising the previous rows' data.

I've tried recording Macro, but I can only get a new row to generate below the row I used to copy from.

**EDIT
I've previously just used record macro and it came out with the following code:

```
Sub NewWayPoint()
'
' NewWayPoint Macro
' Create new Waypoint Row
'

'
Rows("22:22").Select
Selection.Copy
Rows("23:23").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Cheers,
Brad

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried

Comment: change shift from xldown to xlup

Comment: Nah it's not working how I intend to get it to work.. Since I'm a noob at coding, the only work around I can think of is to create a variable that increases in value by 1 everytime I click "Add Waypoint" and then base my numbering and formula off the value inside the variable :\

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out using a cell as a counter:

```
Sub AddWPMacros()
Click_Count_Add
NewWayPoint
End Sub


Sub Click_Count_Add()
Sheets("Passage Plan").RANGE("V6").Value = Sheets("Passage Plan").RANGE("V6").Value + 1
End Sub


Sub NewWayPoint()

Dim Copyrange As String
Dim PasteRange As String

Let Copyrange = RANGE("V6:V6").Cells
Let PasteRange = Copyrange + 1

Rows(Copyrange).Select
Selection.Copy
Rows(PasteRange).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Where the Add Waypoint button activates AddWPMacros and ticks over the counter in a cell. Works a treat !

[image]